# A tricky logic question about spinnes[kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, arduino

I have an Activity with a spinner that has 4 items.
Each position of the spinner sends a command to an Arduino. And this activity **actually has 200 spinners (Its a representation of a matrix)** .

So, the real logic problem is: when this activity is called, each spinner at position 0 sends a command, which is 200 commands sent at once. The Arduino just can't handle that and it gets crazy

My solution would be to have a fifth item with position 0 that does nothing when the activity loads up, the Arduino doesn't receive 200 commands at once, and then this position 0 item gets deleted, lefting with the original 4 item

But I have absolutely no idea how to do that.
Thanks!

SetTrainingRouteActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_training_route)

    SA00.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            //val selectedItem: Any? = parent?.getItemIdAtPosition(position)
            val selectedItem = view as TextView
            if (position == 0) { sendCommand("0000000")
                selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f8faed"))
                selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#606060"))
            }
            if (position == 1) { sendCommand("1000000")
                selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f8faed"))
                selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4500"))
            }
            if (position == 2) { sendCommand("1060000")
                selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"))
                selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#32cd32"))
            }
            if (position == 3) { sendCommand("1100000")
                selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f8faed"))
                selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1e90ff"))
            }
            if (position == 4) { sendCommand("1040000")
                selectedItem.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"))
                selectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff00"))
            }
        }
    }

private fun sendCommand(input: String) {
    if (ControlActivity.arduino_bluetoothSocket != null) {
        try{
            ControlActivity.arduino_bluetoothSocket!!.outputStream.write(input.toByteArray())
        } catch(e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_set_training_route.xml

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/SA00"
     android:prompt="@string/dialog_title"
     android:background="@null"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:spinnerMode="dialog"
     android:entries="@array/IA00" />
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="IA24">
    <item>A24[Off]</item>
    <item>A24[R]</item>
    <item>A24[G]</item>
    <item>A24[B]</item>
    <item>A24[Y]</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Is there code missing here where you call setPosition on the spinner? Unrelated, but this long series of if statements could be replaced with a when statement for clarity.

Comment: Could you describe more? Thank you!

Comment: Do you ever call `spinner.setPosition()` or `spinner.position =` something?

Comment: No, the code is complete.
There's nothing missing...